# dojo1.7 Enhancedgrid is not refreshed when new store is assigned in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, grid, refresh, store

I am working on dojo1.7. I have an EnhancedGrid which I need to refresh with latest data.

> > var gridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
> >                             url:'',
> >                             data:result,
> >                             urlPreventCache: false
> >                         });

```
                grid.store=gridStore;
                grid._refresh();
```

I am fetching some data in required format

var result = {
        "identifier": "id",
    "items": [] //jsonobject
    };

The above code works fine on firefox however on IE I am getting an error 'null is null or not an object'. I am not sure what is going wrong in IE. Is there any other way of changing the store in dojo1.7? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON formatting issue. Can you post the complete JSON data that you are sending from server or check for any errors in JSON.

Another way you can try for refreshing or changing store URL is :

1) Assign empty store to grid initially

2) At runtime, execute `dijit.byId('grid').store.url= 'someurl';`

3) Execute `dijit.byId('grid').store.save();dijit.byId('grid').store.fetch({query:{id: '*'}});`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
When I am refreshing the grid, I am creating a new store and then assigning data to store. then I assigned store to grid.
When I debugged the code I found that grid._refresh fails. JSON format is not an issue as it works fine on firefox.
I have also tried grid.setStore(store) but still getting the same issue.
Code:

store.addCallback(function(response) {
var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
      url:'',
      data:response,
      urlPreventCache: false
     });

     grid.store=store1;

     grid._refresh();

}

Comment: 1) Can you post the JSON too. Firefox is more forgiving when it comes to formatting issues. 2) Create a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.com) for your code and I will try fixing it.

Comment: JSON is not a problem as it is working well with dojo1.5 on all browsers.
When I debug the code using developertool I am not getting the error for setStore(). Can you tell me how to change the store with dojo1.7 when url is not used and data is assigned to store using separate xhrpost? I don't want to use url in the store.
While refreshing the store : 
 grid.store.close();
var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url:'', data:response, urlPreventCache: false });
 grid.setStore(store1); 
 grid._refresh();